# What hash function can I use for keywords?

Tags: c, hash

I am working in C. To store a set of words for searching through them, I am told to save them in a hash table, and that it will reduce the time complexity to a constant.

Can someone help me out with the hash function? Also, if I have around 25 keywords, can I just make a table of size 25 and map each keyword to an index?

Comment: @Drew Dormann no, an element of a project.

Comment: @DrewDormann though you can call it project, but not as such.

Comment: You can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm

Comment: @Kraken: You might want to question whoever suggested a hashtable.  You are incorrect to assume that "constant time" equals "reduced time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to look for a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), a hash function for which collisions don't exist.  The Linux tool [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) (not gprof) can be used to automatically generate a perfect hash function from a set of strings.  As others have pointed out this is unlikely to give you a huge performance boost unless lookup times are a large part of your program, but it should speed up the lookups.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

At just 25 entries, a hash table won't bring you much benefit. Just do a linear search instead.

Comment: but say i am searching frequently for different keywords. then i will be going through n elements for each search.

Comment: Store them is sorted order and do a binary search. ln(25) is rather small.

Comment: Yep. For n = 25, this is not a problem. The overhead of a hashtable: hash your input string at O(k) for k the length of the input, with several arithmetic operations per character; find the right bucket; hop through a linked list with a bunch of pointer indirections and memory accesses; and then _check for string equality anyway_ because you might have a hash collision.

Comment: As I understand from previous question it's not about 25 entries in the table. 25 - is just keywords, that are inserted into the symbol table before parsing. But later in that table will be inserted any other identifiers from the source text.

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus i shouldd have mentioned that here.. what do you think shall i do?

Answer (score 0):

At just 25 strings to match, hashing won't add up to the efficiency. You could look into [Horspool Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) for string matching, that should work well! And as Bo mentioned you could store them in a sorted order and do a binary search. Or you could store your keywords in a [Trie data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (something like 26-ary tree) to search for words. Hope this helps :)